# How to convert a table column data inside eloquent in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, sql-like

I am trying to convert the 'CHECKTIME' table column datetime to string for using the 'LIKE' operator in sql. The LIKE operator is not support the datetaime data type. So, I have to convert it into string to use LIKE. How can I do it in laravel eloquent? My Code in Controller:

```
$dailyData=CheckInOutModel::join('USERINFO', 'USERINFO.USERID', '=', 'CHECKINOUT.USERID')
            ->select('USERINFO.USERID as id','USERINFO.BADGENUMBER as bd', 'USERINFO.NAME as name','USERINFO.Image as photo','CHECKINOUT.*')
            ->where(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),' CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME'),'LIKE',$thisDay.'%')
            ->orderBy('CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME','desc')->get();
```

The SQL Query that work to return the data:

```
SELECT CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
FROM CHECKINOUT
JOIN USERINFO ON USERINFO.USERID=CHECKINOUT.USERID
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 126) LIKE  '2021-11-23%';
```

Comment: What is the `126` in the working query? From what I can see, `CONVERT` only takes 2 parameters. Anyway, you might need a `whereRaw` call to get the equivalent.

Comment: @PaulT. 126 is given by mistake. But I have not any problem with raw query. I just need to convert CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME in string in my eloquent query.

Comment: Try with: `->whereRaw('CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) LIKE ?', $thisDay.'%')`

Comment: so you want to find records by a particular date?

Comment: Why are you converting to a string? Why not just query the date?

Comment: @lagbox yes I want. I use '$thisDay=date('Y-m-d');' in my controller to get today date. And the format datetime save in database is like 2021-11-23 12:59:44.000 . I have also no idea which format this datetime saved in database. that's why I want to use LIKE operator to fetch data.

Comment: @patricus because LIKE operator doesn't support datetime.

Comment: You don't want to convert your database dates to strings and then query that. You just want to query the dates: `where('checktime', '>=', $thisDay)->where('checktime', '<', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($thisDay.' +1 day')))`

Comment: `whereBetween` `whereDate`? ... not sure why you would want to do a string search

Comment: @patricus its work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can use the `whereRaw()` ([see link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw)) method to inject raw SQL in your query.

This would be something like this:

```
$dailyData=CheckInOutModel::join('USERINFO', 'USERINFO.USERID', '=', 'CHECKINOUT.USERID')
            ->select('USERINFO.USERID as id','USERINFO.BADGENUMBER as bd', 'USERINFO.NAME as name','USERINFO.Image as photo','CHECKINOUT.*')
            ->whereRaw('CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) LIKE ?', $thisDay.'%')
            ->orderBy('CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME','desc')->get();
```

But since you are working with dates, it's recomended to use dates all the way and not convert the data to compare strings.
Another approach would be to use `whereBetween` directly with dates. ([see link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses))

Exemple :

```
$dailyData=CheckInOutModel::join('USERINFO', 'USERINFO.USERID', '=', 'CHECKINOUT.USERID')
            ->select('USERINFO.USERID as id','USERINFO.BADGENUMBER as bd', 'USERINFO.NAME as name','USERINFO.Image as photo','CHECKINOUT.*')
            ->whereBetween(
                'CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME', 
                [
                    $thisDay, 
                    date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $thisDay))
                ]
            )->orderBy('CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME','desc')->get();
```

I have over indented the relevent section to make it clear.

Reach out in comments if you have any issue or suggestion to improve it :)